# Using awk to append to the row above the current

Tags: bash, awk

I have a text files where the some text from the first field rolls over onto the next row.

Example

```
Company Name LLC
Company Name2
LLC
Very Good company name but rolls
over
```

I am able to get the rows that have rolled over by

```
awk '{ if (NF ==1) print $0}'
```

I am looking for a way to append the text onto `(NR -1)`

correct output

```
Company Name LLC
Company Name2 LLC
Very Good company name but rolls over
```

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts please do add your expected output in your question to make it more clear.

Comment: can rollover happen more than once?

Comment: Are you sure you can't have `Very Good company name but` / `rolls over`, where two or more words roll over from one line to the next?  It does not appear that your approach to recognizing roll-overs would work for that.

Comment: Can you have a line that's just 1 word (e.g. `Nissan`)  but it's NOT a rollover from the previous line? If so how do you identify that differently from the lines that are rolled over?

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -v ORS= '
    NR>1 { print( NF>1 ? "\n" : OFS ) }
    1;
    END { print "\n" }
' input_file
```

- unset `ORS` so print doesn't emit implicit newlines
- on every line except the first (ie. when `NR>1`), print appropriate delimiter (newline before normal line, `OFS` before overflow)
- then print the actual line (`1` is a minimal "true" pattern/action; which causes the default action to be performed. ie. `print`)
- at the end, print a newline

Comment: This is truly inspired!  What's the value at the end of the program (i.e., the '1') do?

Comment: Very good awk solution

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following `tac` + `awk` code.

```
tac Input_file | 
awk '
NF==1{
  val=$0(val?OFS val:"")
  next
}
NF>1{
  print $0,val
  val=""
}' | 
tac
```

Comment: The file has thousands of rows.

Comment: @JasonAruni, to combine? If this is the case then please add this info in your question AND also let us know from which line onwards till which line you want to add AND what is the logic of adding them, thank you.

Comment: @JasonAruni, Ok, I have edited my solution now, please try edited solution and let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Preliminarily, you are not making use of awk's pattern-action syntax and defaults; `awk NF==1` has the same effect as the command you posted.

But for your Q, in awk you need to buffer the previous line and then decide how to use it:

```
awk 'NF==1{print p,$0; p=""; next} length(p){print p} {p=$0} END{print p}'
```

Or less efficiently but simpler you can do

```
tac | awk 'NF==1{getline t; print t,$0; next} 1' | tac
```

Comment: your first awk emits an empty line when final line is a rollover

Comment: can you explain this code to please, it works well.

```awk 'NF==1{print p,$0; p=""; next} length(p){print p} {p=$0} END{print p}'```

Answer (score 0):

I would use GNU `AWK` for this task following way let `file.txt` content be

```
Company Name LLC
Company Name2
LLC
Very Good company name but rolls
over
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS=""}{print gensub(/\n([^[:space:]]+)(\n|$)/, " \\1\\2", "g")}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
Company Name LLC
Company Name2 LLC
Very Good company name but rolls over
```

Explanation: I set `RS` to empty string so GNU `AWK` treat things between empty lines as rows, in this case whole content as single row. Then I use [`gensub`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function to replace runs of non-whitespace characters after newline character which do occupy whole line. Newline before such run is replaced using space. 1st capturing group is used to said non-whitespace characters, 2nd capturing group allows alternative as such run might be terminated by newline or end of file, whatever it was it is used as replacement value. **Disclaimer**: this solution assumes empty (blank) line is never present in your file.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
    {NF>1 ? a[NR]=$0 : a[NR-1]=a[NR-1] FS $1}
    END{for(i in a) print a[i]}
' file

Company Name LLC
Company Name2 LLC
Very Good company name but rolls over
```

- `NF>1` if more than one field

  - true: `a[NR]=$0` add element (line) to array
  - false: `a[NR-1]=a[NR-1] FS $1` update prev-array-element `NR-1`
- `for(i in a) print a[i]`  print all array-elements

---

Create bash array from awk output

```
$ readarray -t array < <(awk '{NF>1 ? a[NR]=$0 : a[NR-1]=a[NR-1] FS $1} END{for(i in a) print a[i]}' file)
$ declare -p array
declare -a array=([0]="Company Name LLC" [1]="Company Name2 LLC" [2]="Very Good company name but rolls over")
```

Append to bash array

```
$ readarray -t -O "${#array[@]}" array < <(awk '{NF>1 ? a[NR]=$0 : a[NR-1]=a[NR-1] FS $1} END{for(i in a) print a[i]}' file2)
$ declare -p array
declare -a array=([0]="Company Name LLC" [1]="Company Name2 LLC" [2]="Very Good company name but rolls over" [3]="Company Name3 LLC" [4]="Company Name4 LLC" [5]="Very Good company2 name but rolls over")
```

@Jason Aruni

```
readarray -t -O "${#array[@]}" array < <(
     printf "Company Name LLC \nCompany Name2 \nLLC\nVery Good company name but rolls \nover\n" | \
     awk '{NF>1 ? a[NR]=$0 : a[NR-1]=a[NR-1] FS $1} END{for(i in a) print a[i]}'
)

for i in "${array[@]}"; do echo $i; done
```

Output

```
Company Name LLC
Company Name2 LLC
Very Good company name but rolls over
```

Comment: Is it possible to update a bash array in awk, which will be accessible outside of awk? I tried it in this way, but  get an empty array.

```readarray -t -O "${#array[@]}" array < <(awk '{NF>1 ? a[NR]=$0 : a[NR-1]=a[NR-1] FS $1} END{for(i in a) print a[i]}')```

Comment: your file is missing at the end!..  `... print a[i]}' file)`.. tested `declare -a array=([0]="Company Name LLC" [1]="Company Name2 LLC" [2]="Very Good company name but rolls over")`

Comment: I am able to get the output with this code.
```printf "Company Name LLC \nCompany Name2 \nLLC\nVery Good company name but rolls \nover\n" | \
awk '{NF>1 ? a[NR]=$0 : a[NR-1]=a[NR-1] FS $1} END{for(i in a) print a[i]} ``` however with this, my array is empty.

```array=()
printf "Company Name LLC \nCompany Name2 \nLLC\nVery Good company name but rolls \nover\n" | \
readarray -t -O "${#array[@]}" array < <(awk '{NF>1 ? a[NR]=$0 : a[NR-1]=a[NR-1] FS $1} END{for(i in a) print a[i]}')
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
   echo $i
done```

I need the output in an array for further processing.

Comment: You are printing at the wrong position!... You have to pipe your input to awk not to readarray.. Look at my Example

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'NR>1{printf "%s%s", prev, (NF==1 ? OFS : ORS)} {prev=$0} END{print prev}' file
Company Name LLC
Company Name2 LLC
Very Good company name but rolls over
```