# How to remove newlines between lines if next line not starting with a comma?

Tags: regex, awk, text, sed, format

I've exported into a text file all of my text messages and they are formatted as such.

```
, NAME +18001112222, RECV, Text message contents.
, NAME +18001112222, RECV, Text message contents that are run over to 
the line below it.
, NAME +18001112222, SENT, Text message contents that have

multiple lines and empty lines!
, NAME +18001112222, SENT, Text Message contents
```

I know how to remove the empty lines. How would one use awk, sed or grep to move all of these lines, that don't begin with a `,` to the end of the line above it?

Or how would you reformat this to ensure each text message has all of its contents on a single line.

I haven't tried anything yet, because Im unsure where to even begin, thats why I'm here asking for more practiced hands to hopefully provide some practical examples on how to going about solving this issue.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I found this Link in another Question and it has helped alot,    http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/24

Comment: How about [`perl -0777 -pe 's/\n+(?!,)/ /g;'`](https://tio.run/##lcy9CsIwGIXhvVdx7FLF1jYuFRxEpGMdVJxcYv0whTQpyecfeO9VcBNUPNs7nGcvveo6qpRFGGM5LwsMxSTLhBDj52KsisU2xoaujIa8l0dCZQ2TYT8K/n2AlWRIR3AnA3smB7YIWBF0bQh70vaCmj/I62K5@SoreaYgaE6a61a/TA9pDqCm5durez/t8s0OcUdLTiPJ8jxH0hIin@7MsD/rxYMU6XEadd0D) (also see [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/FHiFfh/1))

Comment: @bobblebubble doesn't that delete the final newline in the input? maybe append `(?=.)`?

Comment: Glad that helped!  @jhnc Yes if this is not wanted also to change the lookahead to [`(?!$|,)`](https://regex101.com/r/FHiFfh/2) could suffice.

Answer (score 2):

Same idea as https://stackoverflow.com/a/73030681/10971581 :

```
awk -v ORS= '
    NR>1 && /^, / { print "\n" }
    1;
    END { print "\n" }
' inputfile
```

The input seems to be malformed CSV. One would normally expect fields that could contain newlines or the field delimiter (`,` ) to be quoted.

Note that it is impossible in general to determine if a line that starts with `,`  is a continuation or intended to start a new line. The code above assumes it is always the latter.

Answer (score 1):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
, NAME +18001112222, RECV, Text message contents.
, NAME +18001112222, RECV, Text message contents that are run over to 
the line below it.
, NAME +18001112222, SENT, Text message contents that have

multiple lines and empty lines!
, NAME +18001112222, SENT, Text Message contents
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n,"}{ORS=RT;gsub(/\n/," ");print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
, NAME +18001112222, RECV, Text message contents.
, NAME +18001112222, RECV, Text message contents that are run over to  the line below it.
, NAME +18001112222, SENT, Text message contents that have  multiple lines and empty lines!
, NAME +18001112222, SENT, Text Message contents
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that row separator (`RS`) is newline (`\n`) followed by comma (`,`) then for each line I set output row separator (`ORS`) is current row terminator (`RT`) then replace all newlines (`\n`) in rows by space (depending on your requirement you might need alter that to empty string) then I `print` row which is suffixed by row terminator.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Comment: That would produce output that isn't a valid text file per POSIX as it'd be missing the terminating newline from the last line.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -E ':a;/^,/{N;s/ *\n($|[a-z])/ \1/;ba}' input_file
, NAME +18001112222, RECV, Text message contents.
, NAME +18001112222, RECV, Text message contents that are run over to  the line below it.
, NAME +18001112222, SENT, Text message contents that have  multiple lines and empty lines!
, NAME +18001112222, SENT, Text Message contents
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;/\n$\|\n[^,]/s/\n//;ta;P;D' file
```

Append the next line and if it is empty or does not begin with `,`, remove the newline and go again. Otherwise, print/delete the first line and go again.

N.B.The `D` command inhibits the automatic replenishing of the pattern space with the next line when the pattern space is not empty i.e. stuff is left over from before.

Answer (score 1):

GNU `sed` with th `-z` option:

```
sed -rz ':a;s/\n([^,])/\1/g;ta' inputfile
```

Comment: Also a nice one!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Perl One-Liner](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-perl-one-liners.html) (RexEgg explanation).

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\n+(?!,)/ /g;' yourfile
```

[Here is a demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/FHiFfh/1) or a [bash demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##lcy9CsIwGIXhvVdx7FLF1jYuFRxEpGMdVJxcYv0whTQpyecfeO9VcBNUPNs7nGcvveo6qpRFGGM5LwsMxSTLhBDj52KsisU2xoaujIa8l0dCZQ2TYT8K/n2AlWRIR3AnA3smB7YIWBF0bQh70vaCmj/I62K5@SoreaYgaE6a61a/TA9pDqCm5durez/t8s0OcUdLTiPJ8jxH0hIin@7MsD/rxYMU6XEadd0D)

---

This replaces [one or more](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `\n` *newlines* with space [if not followed by](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) a comma.
To prevent removing newlines at the string end, modify the *lookahead*: [`(?!$|,)`](https://regex101.com/r/FHiFfh/2)